# how to make a set username and password in tkinter python

Tags: python, passwords, tkinter

In tk inter is their away to make a specific username and password open a specific file like if an administrator logs in he would be taken to a administrator page.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="LiftServer(Sign-in)")
w.pack()

e1 = Label(root, text="******************************")
e1.pack()

w1 = Label(root, text="Username")
w1.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

w2 = Label(root, text="Password")
w2.pack()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()

toolbar = Frame(root)


b = Button(toolbar, text="Enter", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="Cancel", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

def callback():
    execfile("signup.txt")
b = Button(toolbar, text="Sign-Up", command=callback, width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure what you are asking but I think this answers it ..

```
def callback():
    if w.get() == "Bob" and w2.get() == "password":
        openfile('file1')
    else:
        openfile('file2')
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\DLLs\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/1209131/Desktop/ftg", line 26, in callback
    if w1.GetValue() == "Bob" and w2.GetValue() == "password":
AttributeError: Label instance has no attribute 'GetValue'                                                               looks like get value is wrong

Comment: thats what I said ... you need to use whatever method you use to "GetValue" for a text box (actually 2 seconds of googling tells me it is just `get()`  instead of `GetValue()`  ...